# How to store timestamp in mysql based on Timezone?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, utc

I want to store timestamp for last_login in my login table. I am creating the time in my DAO layer and updating it in the table when the user logs in. Problem is, I want to update it based on timezone. My code is

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    final TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST");
    formatter.setTimeZone(utc);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 0); // number of days to add
    String date = (String) (formatter.format(c.getTime()));
    Date convertedDate = formatter.parse(date);
    Date timestampObj = new Timestamp(convertedDate.getTime());
```

This is just returning me the timestamp of the server. If the server is in UK, the timestamp is of UK.
I know mysql timestamp stores time in UTC. But rather than saving the time in IST, it is saving time in UK. 
How shall I proceed?

Comment: I would suggest against changing what the timestamp is changed at and rather print a different timezone when the data is fetched from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather, you need to verify your server time.

Check your operating systems time is set to IST (UTC Offset: UTC +5:30).